# Unable to login to serverless.twilio.com

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm unable to login to https://serverless.twilio.com after supplying my Twilio credentials. I have just deployed a function using the twilio cli, but when trying to invoke the function from the serverless URL generated, I get an alert box that prompts me to login. Kindly help. What credentials I'm I supposed to provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function URL should have a unique name, you do not need to log into the URL above, look at the below video and slide deck, they walk you through step-by-step on deploying a Twilio Function via the CLI.

There is also a blog showing how to use with Visual Studio.

[SIGNAL '19 - Leveraging the Serverless API to manage your deployment process](https://speakerdeck.com/dkundel/signal-19-leveraging-the-serverless-api-to-manage-your-deployment-process)

[Leveraging the Serverless API to manage your deployment process](https://youtu.be/XT2Su8gcQWk?list=PLqrz4nXepkz7G6Ba99GaEz_EuXZ6mloAa&t=815)

[Deploy Twilio Functions with the Serverless extension for VSCode](https://www.twilio.com/blog/deploy-twilio-functions-serverless-extension-vscode)